# VB.net String contains reference to DataTable.Column

Tags: vb.net, string

I am using VB.NET and ADO 4.0. Given that I have a string containing a reference to a table.column, can I use the content of the string in a command?

Here is an example of the code I am trying to use:

```
intStatus = 1
strName = "tablename.columnname" & intStatus

'here I would need to have:
tablename.columnname1 
'so I can perform following line
tablename.columnname1 = strValue
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

I got to the point where I can use the string contents as "reference", it seemed to obvious but [strName] does the trick, partially.... When I debug bookableday.room1 remains 0 whilst it should show 6. There might be a conversion issue because the debugger shows me "6" i.s.o. 6 . this is the actual code:

```
Do While intStatus < 14
                    If arrRoomStatus(intStatus) = True Then
                        strName = "bookableday.room" & intStatus
                        [strName] = 6
                        Bookableday.av_avail_id = intAv_avail_id
                        Bookableday.Av_Date = dteAddDate
                        dteAddDate = dteAddDate.AddDays(1)
                        intStatus = intStatus + 1
                        intAv_avail_id = intAv_avail_id + 1
                    Else
                        strName = "bookableday.room" & intStatus
                        [strName] = 5
                        Bookableday.av_avail_id = intAv_avail_id
                        Bookableday.Av_Date = dteAddDate
                        dteAddDate = dteAddDate.AddDays(1)
                        intStatus = intStatus + 1
                        intAv_avail_id = intAv_avail_id + 1
                    End If
```

Comment: Could you add more details of what you are wanting to do. Your question seems a bit vague.

Comment: More information would be extremely helpful.  What type of command?  Without knowing more it will be difficult to assist.  In short what you are asking probably will work, but I need to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you are trying to do is this:

```
tablename.Rows(index)(ColumnName) = value
```

You can reference a column by it's column name, not just the index position.

Try referencing the DataTable by the current row and your column name, like this:

```
'// strName = "bookableday.room" & intStatus
strName = "room" & intStatus
If arrRoomStatus(intStatus) = True Then
  Bookableday(rowIndex)(strName) = 6
Else
  Bookableday(rowIndex)(strName) = 5
End If
```

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your help. though I still have a problem.
My tables name is bookableday and the columns are .room1 .room2 .room3 .Room4  etc...
I want to replace the digit by an integer I can alter in the loop.  I thought I had managed that by adding the [], it doesn't give me errors but the value 5 or 6 is not written to the table.  When I debug I note that the 5 is written as "5" by the debugger...whilst it should be 5 (as my table field is Integer).
Thanks again,

Comment: @user1036354 I'm willing to help more, but you haven't documented the problem very thoroughly.  What is Bookableday?  What is the name of your DataTable?  And the Columns?  Help me help you.

Comment: @user1036354 Updated answer.  Maybe you just need to supply the row index with your column name for your DataTable.